# Не срабатывают события потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, события

Суть такова. В первом потоке происходит поиск файлов и запись переменных и они передаются во вторичный поток, который выясняет размер файла. Для того, чтобы переменные не перезаписывались и передавали правильно я сделал Event. Это событие не дает перезаписать переменные, пока вторичный поток не разрешит. Все-работает вполне устойчиво на 3 файлах, но когда я загружаю 90 файлов, то около 5 файлов выдают ошибку. Я догадываюсь, что событие как-то проскакивает и передает то же самое имя файла во вторичный поток, а т.к. файл открыт уже в другом вторичном потоке, то выдает ошибку прочтения и подсчета размера файла

Основной код

```
HANDLE hEvent1 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, NULL);
//область, которая должна быть защищена, пока не придет сигнал
do
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent1, INFINITE);

    if (!(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) // is it's a file
    {
        if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, file, &part) == 0)
            return FALSE;

        lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);
        //******************************************

        params1.hWnd = hWnd;
        params1.file = (LPCTSTR)file;
        thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadSize, (void*)&params1, 0, NULL);

        //WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
        //******************************************
    }
}
while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); // next file in folder

//вторичный поток, в котором событие переходит в сигнальное состояние
DWORD WINAPI threadSize(void * param1) {
    MsParams_t1 * ptr = (MsParams_t1 *)param1;
    HWND hWnd = ptr->hWnd;
    LPCSTR file = ptr->file;
    SetEvent(hEvent1);
    // Размер файла
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    // Файл
    LPCTSTR lpszSystemInfo = file;

    // Открываем файл
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszSystemInfo,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось открыть файл",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Получаем размер файла
    dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (dwSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось определить размер файла",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "mymutex");
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    sumsize += dwSize;
    char chSize[256];
    sprintf_s(chSize, 256, "%d", sumsize);
    SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, chSize);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    // Выход из программы
    return(0);
}
```

Полный код программы на всякий случай

```
// --- Обязательный включаемый файл
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define ID_EM 3000
#define ID_ES 3001
#define ID_BS 3002
#define ID_BR 3003
#define ID_BP 3004

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    HWND hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders;
} MsParams_t;
static MsParams_t params;
typedef struct
{
    HWND hWnd;
    LPCTSTR file;
} MsParams_t1;
static MsParams_t1 params1;

// --- Описание функции главного окна
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// --- Глобальные переменные
HINSTANCE hInst;        // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
char ClassName[] = "Window";        // Название класса окна
char AppTitle[] = "";   // Заголовок главного окна
DWORD sumsize = 0;
HANDLE hThr;
HANDLE thread;
TCHAR buf[512];
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "mymutex");
HANDLE hMutex1 = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "mymutex1");
HANDLE hEvent1 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, NULL);

DWORD WINAPI threadSize(void * param1) {
    MsParams_t1 * ptr = (MsParams_t1 *)param1;
    HWND hWnd = ptr->hWnd;
    LPCSTR file = ptr->file;
    SetEvent(hEvent1);
    // Размер файла
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    // Файл
    LPCTSTR lpszSystemInfo = file;

    // Открываем файл
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszSystemInfo,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось открыть файл",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Получаем размер файла
    dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (dwSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Не удалось определить размер файла",
            "Ошибка",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    hMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "mymutex");
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    sumsize += dwSize;
    char chSize[256];
    sprintf_s(chSize, 256, "%d", sumsize);
    SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, chSize);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);

    // Выход из программы
    return(0);
}

DWORD WINAPI file_seek(void * param)
{
    MsParams_t * ptr = (MsParams_t *)param;
    HWND hWnd = ptr->hWnd;
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName = ptr->lpszFileName;
    BOOL bInnerFolders = ptr->bInnerFolders;
    LPTSTR part;
    char tmp[MAX_PATH]; // temporary array
    char name[MAX_PATH];
    char file[MAX_PATH];

    HANDLE hSearch = NULL;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    memset(&wfd, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    //search in embeded folders for first
    if (bInnerFolders)
    {
        if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, tmp, &part) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        lstrcpy(name, part);
        lstrcpy(part, "*.*");

        //if folder exists, down to it
        wfd.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        if (!((hSearch = FindFirstFile(tmp, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
            do
            {
                //if current folder is a service folders? which no need to check
                if (!strncmp(wfd.cFileName, ".", 1) || !strncmp(wfd.cFileName, "..", 2))
                    continue;

                if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) //if it's a folder
                {
                    // making a new path
                    char next[MAX_PATH];
                    if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, next, &part) == 0)
                        return FALSE;
                    lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);
                    lstrcat(next, "\\");
                    //cout << next << endl; 
                    lstrcat(next, name);
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); //finding next file in folder
                                                   //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            FindClose(hSearch); // closing a search descriptor
    }

    if ((hSearch = FindFirstFile(lpszFileName, &wfd)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return TRUE;


    do
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hEvent1, INFINITE);

        if (!(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) // is it's a file
        {
            if (GetFullPathName(lpszFileName, MAX_PATH, file, &part) == 0)
                return FALSE;

            lstrcpy(part, wfd.cFileName);
            //******************************************

            params1.hWnd = hWnd;
            params1.file = (LPCTSTR)file;
            thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadSize, (void*)&params1, 0, NULL);

            //WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
            //******************************************
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hSearch, &wfd)); // next file in folder
    FindClose(hSearch); // close search descriptor
    char chSize[256];
    sprintf_s(chSize, 256, "%d", sumsize);
    SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, chSize);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

// --- Функция WinMain
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, // В Win32 всегда равен NULL
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    // Указатель на командную строку. Он // позволяет
    // приложению получать данные из командной строки.
    int nCmdShow
    // Определяет, как приложение первоначально 
    // отображается на дисплее: пиктограммой
    // (nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE) 
    // или в виде открытого окна                    //(nCmdShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL).
)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;    // Структура для информации о классе окна
    HWND hWnd;  // Дескриптор главного окна приложения
    MSG msg;    // Структура для хранения сообщения
                // Сохраняем дескриптор экземпляра приложения в глобальной
                // переменной, чтобы при необходимости воспользоваться им в
                // функции окна.
    hInst = hInstance;

    // --- Проверяем, было ли приложение запущено ранее.
    // Воспользуемся функцией FindWindow, которая позволяет
    // найти окно верхнего 
    // уровня по имени класса или по заголовку окна:
    // HWND FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName,
    // LPCTSTRlpWindowName);
    // Через параметр lpClassName передается указатель на
    // текстовую строку, в которую необходимо записать имя
    // класса искомого окна. На базе одного и того же класса 
    // можно создать несколько окон. Если необходимо найти 
    // окно с заданным заголовком, то имя заголовка следует
    // передать через параметр lpWindowName. Если же подойдет 
    // любое окно, то параметр lpWindowName может иметь
    // значение NULL.
    if ((hWnd = FindWindow(ClassName, NULL)) != NULL)
    {
        // Пользователь может не помнить, какие приложения уже
        // запущены, а какие нет. Когда он запускает приложение, 
        // то ожидает, что на экране появится его главное окно.
        // Поэтому, если приложение было запущено ранее,
        // целесообразно активизировать и выдвинуть на передний
        // план его главное окно. Это именно то, к чему приготовился
        // пользователь.
        if (IsIconic(hWnd)) ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

        // Найдена работающая копия - работа новой копии
        // прекращается.
        return FALSE;
    }

    // --- Работающая копия не найдена - функция WinMain
    // приступает к инициализации. Заполнение структуры
    // WNDCLASS для регистрации класса окна.
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;       // Имя класса окон
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    // Адрес оконной функции
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // Стиль класса 
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;       // Экземпляр приложения
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    // Пиктограмма для окон
    wc.hCursor = NULL;
    // Курсор мыши для окон
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    // Кисть для окон
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;         // Ресурс меню окон
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;          // Дополнительная память
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;          // Дополнительная память
                                // Pегистрация класса окна.
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Создаем главное окно приложения.
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
        ClassName,          // Имя класса окон
        AppTitle,           // Заголовок окна 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // Стиль окна
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // X-координаты 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Y-координаты 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Ширина окна
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          // Высота окна
        NULL,           // Дескриптор окна-родителя
        NULL,           // Дескриптор меню окна
        hInst,      // Дескриптор экземпляра приложения
        NULL);      // Дополнительная информация
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        // Окно не создано, выдаем предупреждение.
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Create: error", AppTitle, MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hEditMask = CreateWindow("EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
        , 10, 40, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EM, hInstance, NULL);
    char buf1[50] = { "F:\\TestProg\\*.txt" };
    SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_EM, buf1);
    HWND hEditSize = CreateWindow("EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
        , 10, 80, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_ES, hInstance, NULL);

    HWND hButtonStart = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Search", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 35, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BS, 0, NULL);
    HWND hButtonResume = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Resume", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 65, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BR, 0, NULL);
    HWND hButtonPause = CreateWindow((LPCSTR)"button", (LPCSTR)"Pause", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        180, 95, 100, 27, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_BP, 0, NULL);

    // Отображаем окно.
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // Обновляем содержимое клиентской области окна.
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Запускаем цикл обработки очереди сообщений.
    // Функция GetMessage получает сообщение из очереди, 
    // выдает false при выборке из очереди сообщения WM_QUIT
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        // Преобразование некоторых сообщений, 
        // полученных с помощью клавиатуры
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        // Отправляем сообщение оконной процедуре
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

// --- Функция окна
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char *str = (char *)"First Windows aplication";

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_BS:
        {
            sumsize = 0;
            params.hWnd = hWnd;
            params.bInnerFolders = true;
            SetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_ES, "");
            GetDlgItemText(hWnd, ID_EM, buf, 512);
            params.lpszFileName = (LPCTSTR)buf;
            hThr = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)file_seek, (void*)&params, 0, NULL);
        }; break;
        case ID_BR:
        {
            ResumeThread(hThr);
        }; break;
        case ID_BP:
        {
            SuspendThread(hThr);
        }; break;
        }
    }; break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hDC;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // Получить контекст окна

        // Рисование узора
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // Освободить контекст окна
    }; break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        // Если данная функция является оконной функцией
        // главного окна, то следует в очередь сообщений
        // приложения послать сообщение WM_QUIT 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }; break;

    // Необработанные сообщения передаем в стандартную
    // функцию обработки сообщений по умолчанию.
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0l;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопрос уже был вчера.

Comment: Во-первых, вчера был не этот вопрос. Во-вторых, даже на вчерашний вопрос не был получен ответ, но он уже не актуален

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаёте params1.file = (LPCTSTR)file как указатель на строку. Потом в функции вы читаете этот указатель LPCSTR file = ptr->file; и вызываете SetEvent. Обе функции используют одну и ту же строку, т.к. передача по указателя не создаёт копию строки.

Вы можете или перенести SetEvent после открытия файла, когда имя файла вам больше не важно:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszSystemInfo,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);
SetEvent(hEvent1);
```

Или передавать в функцию threadSize копию строки. Например сделать параметр имени файла std::string. Тем самым поток threadSize будет использовать только собственные ресурсы.

Comment: Я как раз так попробовал сделать и потом увидел ответ. Тем не менее спасибо за то, что объяснил почему так происходит.

Comment: А скопировать наверно все же не получится, ибо переменные константные

Comment: Константную переменную нельзя изменять, но её содержимое можно копировать в другую переменную.